# Best way to represent constraints on values in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the best way to express that, say, an `Int` field or parameter should never be negative?

The first thing that comes to mind is an annotation on the type, like `case class Foo(x: Int @NotNegative)`. But I'd have to invent my own annotation, and there wouldn't be any sort of compile-time checking or anything.

Is there a better way?

Comment: See also this thread on the Scala forum: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/6958

Comment: and this recent paper: http://www.springerlink.com/content/978-3-642-16611-2/#section=815757&page=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using a separate data type?

```
class Natural private (val value: Int) {
   require(value >= 0)

   def +(that:Natural) = new Natural(this.value + that.value)
   def *(that:Natural) = new Natural(this.value * that.value)
   def %(that:Natural) = new Natural(this.value % that.value)
   def |-|(that:Natural) = Natural.abs(this.value - that.value) //absolute difference

   override def toString = value.toString
}

object Natural {
  implicit def nat2int(n:Natural) = n.value
  def abs(n:Int) = new Natural(math.abs(n))
}
```

Usage:

```
val a = Natural.abs(4711)
val b = Natural.abs(-42)
val c = a + b
val d = b - a  // works due to implicit conversion, but d is typed as Int
println(a < b) //works due implicit conversion
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly better (?), perhaps, but still no compiler check: `require(x >= 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Contracts and invariants are not supported by Scala at this time.

Comment: This should be clarified somewhat.  There is no direct support for contracts/invariants in the language (e.g. pre-/post-conditions as part of the method signature), but there is some support for runtime checks in the standard library.  `require` and its relatives are used to specify pre-conditions, and `ensuring` can be used to specify post-conditions.  As @Landei demonstrated, the type system can also be used to specify contracts.

Comment: @Aaron I've learned contracts and invariants to be compile-time assertions. Run time checks are easy to implement in any language. As for using the type system, it can be used to some extent, but it is cumbersome and inconvenient where contracts and invariants are concerned.

Comment: Actually, the term "contracts" comes from Eiffel which only enforces them dynamically.  Invariants are also usually enforced dynamically.  They are easy to implement in any (non-total) language, but Eiffel has special syntactic sugar for them.

Comment: @James Never got to learn Eiffel, but it is disappointed to learn it doesn't enforce contracts statically.